How to fetch GA4 events such as add_payment_info, page_info
Does anyone know an API to fetch the following events from GA4: add_payment_info, add_shipping_info, page_view, etc? I'm aware that there is an API for requesting Dimensions and Metrics (runReport), but I can't find how to make a request to receive specifically those data
Can it be stored directly in Firebase? Can I connect to it?

So those would be event names. You use the data api and filter the event name field by these values and you'll get only them.

Thanks to BNazaruk I managed to fetch what I wanted. Here is what the code looks like:
   analyticsClient.runReport({
        property: `properties/${propertyId}`,
        dateRanges: [dateRange],
        dimensions: [{name: 'eventName'}],
        metrics: [{name: 'eventCount'}],
        dimensionFilter: {
          filter: {
            fieldName: 'eventName',
            inListFilter: { values: ['add_payment_info', 'add_shipping_info'] },
          },
        },
      })

As a dimension, it should be eventName, as a metric I used events count - eventCount, and inside the filter I included those events. You can also use this tool to test possible params https://ga-dev-tools.google/ga4/query-explorer/
